# Custom UIPickerView with locale compatibility

Tags: objective-c, ios, datetime, nsdateformatter

I am making a custom TimePicker from a UIPickerView. I have it working great except when it comes to displaying the hours. I want it to function just like the `UIDatePicker` so that it follows the users `Locale` setting. If they have French selected, the time should display in 24 hour format. If they have US it should display in 12 hour format.

I have an array `hoursArray` that goes from 0 - 23. I then run this code to convert it to the needed format. However it is not wanting to change to 24 hour format if that option is set in the Settings -> International section

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];//[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"H"];
NSDate *tempDate = [dateFormatter dateFromString:[hoursArray objectAtIndex:row]];
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h"];

return [dateFormatter stringFromDate:tempDate];
```

I tried changing `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"h"];` to `[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"H"];` since Apples doc says the users personal locale setting will override it, but this doesn't seem to be the case.

How do I get the `dateFormatter` to follow the users locale setting properly?

Answer (score 0):

In my case, the overriding of users preferences worked fine, and that was a bad thing for me.!!! Try setting the locale of your date formatter as

```
[dateFormatter setLocale:[NSLocale systemLocale]];
```

If that didnt work, try removing the code where you set the locale because the NSDateFormatter automatically considers the user settings.